# BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed! help to solve it. Im using unity version 2022.2.0b16

Tags: unity-game-engine

this problem may be due to admob, because the new project was built without admob
all problem
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <15b70f2d388949858617e971ef87b8eb>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at :0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I tried without admob and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

[Open Editor Log][1]

Hello! Check the editor log file for more details about the error.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIHWJ.png